# remotely run a powershell script to a windows server amazon web services(android)

Tags: android, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I don't know how can I run a powershell script remotely to my Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base in Amazon cloud. Basically my architecture is my android app will upload a group of images to amazon s3 in a certain bucket, then I want to run a script in my windows server that will copy those images, process it, then send the processed images back to amazon s3 bucket. I wonder how can I invoke those script? Or send a command from a lambda function to my windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have S3 pushing [event notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to an SQS queue, and have a process on your Windows server polling for new messages on that queue.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I want to ask is what are the other ways to receive messages efficiently? What I tried so far is I  run a forever loop power shell script in my ec2 instance, and it receives sqs messages, but I discovered that there is charge in every request.

Comment: To reduce SQS requests make sure you are using SQS Long Polling: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html If you wanted to have messages pushed to the server instead, you could configure SNS to push to a HTTP endpoint, and setup that endpoint on your server.